# JWT use refresh Token as access Token

Tags: jwt

What if a refresh token is hijacked by a hacker, and then he tries to use the refresh token as the access token? The validator in the backend will see that the refresh token is valid and not expired? Is there any mechanism that will identify the refresh token as a refresh token?

Comment: There's no generic answer to this, because JWT itself doesn't define concepts like "access token" and "refresh token", it's just a format for tokens in general. The answer for any well-designed system using those token types is yes, they will have different content. Without more context, it's impossible to say more specifically.

Comment: mhm, that does not answer my question. Is there any flag which will identify the token as a specific one? A Claim for example?

Comment: As I say, without any context, it's **impossible** to answer your question. JWT does not specify any definition of "refresh token", so any such claim would be defined by some other standard or implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hacker can only use the refresh token to get a new access token. The refresh token can't be used to access any API's or other services. The refresh token is usually just a random string and not a JWT-token.

The backend often returns a new refresh token after each use and if the same refresh token is used twice (by the hacker + the normal user) then the user is blocked. (one time refresh tokens)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just figured out that a python backend framework called "django" uses a jwt token as the refresh token and not a random string. Also, the access token and the refresh token are flagged with a claim that tells whether it is a refresh or access.

Comment: ok! different providers returns different "refresh token formats",